# LINQ to XML !StartWith

Tags: c#, linq

I trying to get all attribute values from xml file where value doesn't start with some text

i have this code

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
    (from el in xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName)
     where (string)el.Attribute(attributeName)  !StartWith("abc")
     select el);
```

How can i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a valid expression, e.g.

```
where !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartsWith("abc")
```

It's important to understand that what goes into a LINQ `where` clause isn't "magic" syntax - it's just a normal expression, which can use the *range variables* declared by the query expression (`el` in this case). So you should have asked yourself, "If I were writing this not in LINQ, and I had a variable called `el` referring to an element, how would I have written an `if` condition to check that the attribute value didn't start with `abc`?"

(I use the explicit conversion when the attribute can be missing and I want to just get a null, but in this case you're going to go bang when the attribute's missing anyway, and you just want the string value, so you might as well use the `Value` property.)

Note that as you've *only* got a `where` clause here (and a trivial `select`) it would probably be more readable to use the non-query-expression form:

```
var elements = xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName)
                      .Where(el => !el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartsWith("abc"));
```

Comment: I got this error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

It works fine for another case as:
where (string)el.Attribute(attributeName) != attributeValue select el

Answer (score 0):

try with this ( adjust your startwith)

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = 

from el in xmlFile.Root.Elements(elementName) 
where ! el.Attribute(attributeName).Value.StartWith("abc") 
select el;
```